# Laravel call controller from view without refresh page

Tags: ajax, laravel

I need to call a method on a controller without reload the page.
Here the problem,
I have a jwplayer reciving a playlist via Rss from the controller, and then when the playlist end's I need to get another playlist from the controller, but I can't refresh the page (That's the easier way) because the player don't do fullscreen automatically.

How can I do it.

thanks.

Comment: You need to use 'ajax' for this

Answer (score 5):

If your controller has all the required data then you can simply
[inject the controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection) in your view.

If the data is changing based on the input supplied then you have to use the ajax calls to get the new data. You can send the next ajax call on the end of current playlist.
A simple ajax call would be like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'fetch-data',
            method: 'post',
            success: function () {
                console.log("done");
                //do something
            },error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log(xhr.status+" ,"+" "+ajaxOptions+", "+thrownError);
                }
            }
        });
```

and in your routes file

```
Route::post('fetch-data', 'MyController@fetchData');
```

Comment: @PedroValente please accept the answer and upvote :)